# Using EventToCommand spoils DesignView in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, mvvm-light

I'm using the latest Visual Studio:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038
```

When I create a new WPF project (TargetFrameworkVersion: v4.5.2) and add `MvvmLightLibs` (latest Version: 5.2.0.0) by NuGet inside the following XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="MergedDirectoriesTest.Views.SubView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MergedDirectoriesTest.ViewModels"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight">
    ...
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource FormTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TextEnteredCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
</UserControl>
```

`EventToCommand` will be marked as error

```
Cannot add instance of type 'EventToCommand' to a collection of type 'TriggerActionCollection'. Only items of type 'T' are allowed.
```

If I change the XML namespace to

```
<UserControl ...
         xmlns:command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform">
```

I get this

```
The type 'EventToCommand' from assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in a Windows Presentation Framework 4 project.
```

For your information: I use the `System.Windows.Interactivity` provided by MVVMLight. As far as I know it's the newest version:

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.2.0.0\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Comment: This is exactly my problem. How did you solve it? (or didn't you?)